# field many2one with function

Tags: python, odoo

I need to create many2one field.but it should need to filter data, so how can i do this this is my code : 
1- the field that i want to filter is 'compte_id'

```
class AccountMove(models.Model):
    _name = 'account.move'
    _inherit = 'account.move'

    compte_id=fields.Many2one('account.account',string='Compte Budgétaire')
```

2- i need the field 'compte_id' contain the values which is  stored in 'account_id' the account_id belong to table :

```
class FicheLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'm_gov.account.fiche.line'

    account_id = fields.Many2one('account.account', string='Rubrique' ,required=False)
```

please help me

Comment: doesn't this work `compte_id=fields.Many2one('m_gov.account.fiche.line',string='Compte Budgétaire')`?

Comment: i had try that but isnt work

Comment: you'd have to specify exactly what you mean by it doesn't work....cuz that syntax is perfectly valid. you probably need to re-edit your question and explain better